# What das VF in VF2 algorithm stand for?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm, isomorphism

Does anyone know what VF in VF2 alogorithm stands for?

Looks like an easy question, but neither Google nor Google Scholar could tell me.

I've learned that you have to introduce an abbreviation before you use it but apparently everybody agreed that there is an exception when it comes to VF2.

Comment: Possibly Vento & Foggia

Comment: Yes, that sounds logical to me. Thank you! Check this paper: http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/797762/